# GPS application with google api run my emulator but not run my phone

Tags: android

I have a tts & gps application with google api, display a map and markers on map.

when i run this app on emulator, the app works as expected but not works well in my phone with apk

I think there's a problem with the api version, but I don't know what to do.

here's my code and i attached this image which not working on my phone

if press the button the marker show my location

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kLRI.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.codingflow.texttospeechexample"
    >

    <permission android:name="wonpa.alwaysweb.com.myloctest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="wonpa.alwaysweb.com.myloctest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    enter code here
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TextToSpeech">


        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my api key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

I'm sorry if i show unnessary code

Comment: in addition my phone is galaxy s21, emulator that i used is nexus 5x api 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a problem if you install the application on your device directly from Android Studio via a USB Debugging mode? If not, then the problem is with generating a signed APK for your device.

Also you need to secure your API key first: [Using API Keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#console).
Take out the API KEY in string resources like that

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Comment: thnks a lot i solved my problem base on it